# Use repeated column value as section header in tablix

Tags: reporting-services, frontend

I'm looking for a way to format a SharePoint report using a tablix to create a labeled series of individual lists from a single data set. (Unfortunately, searching only turned up a lot of stuff about tablix headers disappearing on subsequent pages, which is not the problem I'm working on here).

I have a query set up to return results that look something like this:

```
List Name, List Item
A, 1
A, 2
A, 3
B, 4
B, 5
C, 6
C, 7
```

I would like to find a front-end trick to display them as follows:
**A**
1
2
3

**B**
4
5

**C**
6
7

So, break the result set any time the value in the label column changes, and use the new value as a header for the corresponding group, formatted separately. I know I can create a tablix group that would show the repeated value in the left-hand column, but that kind of presentation isn't going to work for my client--they really want a top-labeled series of lists.

I know I could just put in a whole bunch of different tables, but doing it with a single tablix would be a lot easier (since I have about 40 sub-lists to do), and would suppress any list categories that are blank without needing an additional workaround.

Apologies in advance if I've missed anything obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a row group in SSRS to the tablix.  In desinger go to the lower left under 'Row Groups'.  By default you should have a '(Details)' or equivalent.  Right Click that and choose add 'Parent Group'.  Ensure you select to add a page header if you want detail of the group on a seperate row.

Comment: I'd looked at this, but didn't want the category labels to end up in the left-hand column. However, it looks like if I use a "Page Header" (why is it called 'page header' when it has nothing to do with the page?) I can get an extra row where I can repeat the category label and format appropriately -- thanks! I figured there had to be a way to do this...